# Rolling delinquiency calculation for a dataframe

Tags: r, rolling-computation

I am new to R and trying to get a work around to calculate the 3 months delinquicy on a rolling basis.

My dataframe consists of (CID, acquistion_date and delinquient)

i am trying to create a new dataftrame with a 4th column appended (Roll_deliquency) ie count of delinquient in the last 3 months). As soon as we have a new customer id we start again with the first transaction of that customer. Roll_Deliquiency is the total count of  delinquient **of last 3 months** **only**.

the expected result is as below

```
CID AQ_DATE   Delinquient Roll_Deliquiency
103   2007/03/18    1       0
103   2007/04/03    0       1
103   2007/04/17    0       1
103   2007/05/03    0       1
103   2007/05/17    1       1
103   2007/06/02    1       2
103   2007/06/16    1       3
103   2007/07/02    1       3
103   2008/01/03    1       0
103   2008/01/17    1       1
103   2008/02/02    0       2
103   2008/02/16    1       2
105   2007/01/01    1       0
105   2007/01/11    1       1 
105   2007/02/10    1       2
105   2007/02/14    0       3
105   2007/02/17    1       3    
105   2007/02/17    1       4
105   2007/02/17    1       5
105   2007/04/02    0       5  
105   2007/04/10    1       5
```

Can someone please help me with the R code? I tried using rolling apply but not able to customise the same as per the need.

Comment: I'd say you want to use `cumsum`, but your example `Roll_Delinquincy` does not match `cumsum`. Explain more clearly what the column is. because it is clearly not the cumulative number of delinquents up to that time.

Comment: NO it is not cumsum. I have modified the problem for better clarity. please let me know if you still have difficulty in understanding the logic.

Comment: Are you sure there are supposed to be three 5's at the bottom of the right collumn?

Answer (score 0):

This might not be what you want, but it is the best I can do with my current understanding of the problem.  For each person and each date in the data file I went back in time 90 days and summed the number of delinquencies.  My results are stored in the vector `my.count`.  My results do not match `Roll_Deliquiency`.  However, maybe this will get you started.  If you provide additional information on how `Roll_Deliquiency` is calculated I might be able to modify the code below.  I might also clean up the code a little soon.  It currently includes some variables I did not end up using to obtain my answer.

```
df.1 <- read.table(text='
CID AQ_DATE   Delinquient Roll_Deliquiency
103   2007/03/18    1       0
103   2007/04/03    0       1
103   2007/04/17    0       1
103   2007/05/03    0       1
103   2007/05/17    1       1
103   2007/06/02    1       2
103   2007/06/16    1       3
103   2007/07/02    1       3
103   2008/01/03    1       0
103   2008/01/17    1       1
103   2008/02/02    0       2
103   2008/02/16    1       2
105   2007/01/01    1       0
105   2007/01/11    1       1
105   2007/02/10    1       2
105   2007/02/14    0       3
105   2007/02/17    1       3
105   2007/02/17    1       4
105   2007/02/17    1       5
105   2007/04/02    0       5
105   2007/04/10    1       5', header=T, colClasses=c('character', 'character', 'integer', 'integer'))

df.1$AQ_DATE2 <- as.Date(df.1$AQ_DATE, "%Y/%m/%d")

df.1$running.count = sequence(rle(df.1$CID)$lengths)
df.1

max.value <- data.frame(id.max = with(df.1, tapply(running.count, CID, function(x) x[length(x)])))
max.value

max.value$CID <- row.names(max.value)
max.value

all.data  <- merge(max.value, df.1, by=c('CID'), all = TRUE)
all.data

my.count <- rep(0, nrow(all.data))

m <- 1

for(i in length(unique(all.data$CID)):1) {

  all.data.i <- subset(all.data, all.data$CID == max.value$CID[i])

    print(all.data.i)

     for(j in nrow(all.data.i):1) {

        for(k in j:1) {

           if(((j-k) >  1) &
             (as.numeric(all.data.i$AQ_DATE2[j] - all.data.i$AQ_DATE2[k+1]) <= 90)  &    
             (as.numeric(all.data.i$AQ_DATE2[j] - all.data.i$AQ_DATE2[k  ]) >  90)) my.count[m] = sum(all.data.i$Delinquient[(k+1):j]) 

           if(((j-k) == 1) &
              as.numeric(all.data.i$AQ_DATE2[j] - all.data.i$AQ_DATE2[k])   >  90)  my.count[m] = all.data.i$Delinquient[j]

           if((k == 1) &
              as.numeric(all.data.i$AQ_DATE2[j] - all.data.i$AQ_DATE2[1])   <= 90)  my.count[m] = sum(all.data.i$Delinquient[1:j])

         } 

     m = m + 1

     }     

}

my.count

 [1] 6 5 6 5 4 3 3 2 1 3 2 2 1 4 4 3 2 1 1 1 1
```

Comment: Mark I guess your answer is not matching only in cases where there are more than 1 transaction for the same date and in cases where the count is set to 0. I am ok with that and trying to catch up with your code. Moreover i also observe you are displaying the records in descending order..

Comment: Roll_deliquiency logic:for row1 Roll_Deliquiency is 0 as there are no ealier records. same for row9 (as it is start of new period) and row13 as its a new customer. for row6 Roll_Deliquiency is 2 because if you traverse upwards you would see all aq_date is within 3 months. we don't count the current row deliquiecy. similarly row7 is 3 because AQ_DATE for row7 is 2007/06/16 and if you traverse upwards ie from row 6 to row1 again all the AQ_DATE for each row is within 90 days of row7

Comment: You can reverse the order of the elements in my.count by using: rev(my.count).